# Azure DevOps Pipelines: Back to free tier from paid agent?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We are currently on the [free tier of Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs?view=azure-devops&tabs=ms-hosted) which comes with 1800 free build minutes per month.

As we sometimes hit resource constraints and witness a lot of variation on the build runtime we are considering switching to a paid agent hoping that we will get more performance or at least consistency on the hosted build servers compared to the free tier.

If the paid agent does not come up to our expectation, is there a way to get back to the free tier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the paid agent does not come up to our expectation, is there a way to get back to the free tier?

Yes, you can simply change the `Paid parallel jobs` to `0` to remove the paid agents.

[image]

Or [remove billing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/billing/change-azure-subscription?view=azure-devops#remove-your-subscription) will also remove the paid agents.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can return to the free tier, you just have to take into account the cut-off date of your bill